# How to put JSON values into a list Python

Tags: python

I have a json list that looks like this:

```
{
    "callback": [{
            "id": "R_puFk4fZ8m1lE4bD",
            "set": "Default Response Set",
            "ace": "asdf",
            "date": "asdfdsa",
            "1": "asdf",
            "2": "s",
            "3": "3",
            "4": "1",
            "zone": "0",
            "long": "33.564498901367",
            "lat": "-112.00869750977"
        }
    ]
}
```

My actual data has a lot of json objects within the list and I am wondering how I would put the numbers between "date" and "zone" in a separate list within the json. The numbers vary between the json objects, but they are always in between the "date" and "zone" values.

What would I do to transform it into this:

```
{
    "callback": [{
            "id": "R_puFk4fZ8m1lE4bD",
            "set": "Default Response Set",
            "ace": "asdf",
            "date": "asdfdsa",
            "Q": [
                "1": "asdf",
                "2": "s",
                "3": "3",
                "4": "1"
            ],
            "zone": "0",
            "long": "33.564498901367",
            "lat": "-112.00869750977"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note: Nothing is "always between 'date' and 'zone'" because that is equivalent to a Python dictionary and the ordering is not guaranteed. Are they the only keys that are numeric (represented as strings)?

Comment: @roganjosh Oh okay, thank you. They are keys represented as strings, but not all of the callbacks are numeric representations of strings, some are just strings.

Comment: ok... maybe you could go the other way round. Barring those keys that you want to capture, is the list of keys you _don't_ want to capture always the same?

Comment: These aren't JSON values, they're just Python native data structures. They don't become JSON until you serialize them as such, which happens when you're ready to output them -- for the common case, intent to later serialize a datastructure to JSON doesn't have anything at all to do with how you should be handling/manipulating it earlier (which is to say, well over 50% of the questions tagged JSON on this site *shouldn't be*, this one among them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am sorry, I took off the JSON tag

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you I will try that. Seems to be the only direction I can go.

Comment: Are all the rest of the fields static and the dynamic fields are the ones you want to group? `if key not in ["id", "set", "ace", "date", ..., "lat"]:`

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes. Exactly

Comment: Good idea @TemporalWolf, although it'd be more efficient to use a set rather than a list.

Comment: @TemporalWolf What do you mean by static and dynamic?

Comment: @SamChats if both lists are variable it's a lot harder to separate them. Since the don't include is static, that's the one you should test on.

Comment: @SamChats Static meaning the fields like "id", "set", "ace", "lat", "long", and "zone". Dynamic are the keys that are changing so in my example "1", "2", "3", "4"

Comment: @SamChats The keys in the `"Q"` list can change, so they're dynamic. The other keys don't change, so they're static.

Comment: Thank you @TemporalWolf if you post that as your answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort them out via set membership (as PM 2Ring mentioned, set membership is faster O(1)):

```
def group_questions(source_dct):
    meta_tags = {"id", "set", "ace", "date", "zone", "long", "lat"}

    result_dct = {"Q": {}}
    for key in source_dct:
        if key not in meta_tags:
            result_dct["Q"][key] = source_dct[key]
        else:
            result_dct[key] = source_dct[key]
    return result_dct
```

Result (note dictionaries are not ordered):

```
>>> print group_questions(dct)
{'set': 'Default Response Set', 
 'ace': 'asdf', 
 'zone': '0', 
 'long': '33.564498901367', 
 'Q': {'1': 'asdf', 
       '3': '3', 
       '2': 's', 
       '4': '1'}, 
 'lat': '-112.00869750977', 
 'date': 'asdfdsa', 
 'id': 'R_puFk4fZ8m1lE4bD'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `int()` function to check for integer keys:

```
new_list = []
for old_data in old_list: #old_list is the value of 'callback' key
    data = {'Q': {}}
    for key in old_data.keys():
        try:
            num = int(key)
            data['Q'][key] = old_data[key]
        except ValueError: # stringy keys
            data[key] = old_data[key]
    new_list.append(data)
```

Now, printing `new_list` using something like `json.dumps()` will give something like:

```
[
    {
        "Q": {
            "1": "asdf",
            "2": "s",
            "3": "3",
            "4": "1"
        },
        "id": "R_puFk4fZ8m1lE4bD",
        "set": "Default Response Set",
        "ace": "asdf",
        "date": "asdfdsa",
        "zone": "0",
        "long": "33.564498901367",
        "lat": "-112.00869750977"
    }
]
```

Comment: This assumes `Q` should contain all elements whose key is an `int`. This may or may not satisfy the OP.

Comment: @TemporalWolf No it doesn't do that. `Q` has string keys. See my output.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as TemporalWolf said not all of the keys that I need to capture are integers.

Comment: @jdoe I'm sorry but do you mean that there are keys other that just "numbers" you want in `Q`?

Comment: No, what I mean is that in  this example the keys that I want to capture are "1","2","3","4". But in some of my other data the keys could be "q1","q2","q3","q4". Or they could be "one","two","three","four".

Comment: @jdoe Oh I understand your point. So you originally wanted to separate the keys which were being displayed between the `date` and `zone` keys.

Comment: @SamChats Exactly the problem is that the data that I am getting does not have any concrete rules for the naming of the questions. I need to put all of the questions into a list so I can create a csv file to upload to RedShift